# libcurl C++: issue with printing responses when multiplexing

Tags: c++, libcurl, http2, multiplexing

**Goal:**

To modify the `libcurl` example for `HTTP/2 multiplexing` that [can be found here](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/http2-download.html) to save a payload response as it arrives into some buffer, instead of writing it to a file like the aforementioned example currently does. The payload within the buffer would then be available for things such as printing, searching for strings etc.

**Expected output:**

Program should print out each received payload response to `stdout` whenever the `callback` function detects that one has been delivered.

**Actual output:**

Sometimes the program works as expected for a small number of transfers (see line of code `int num_transfers = 3` in `main()` further below). If the number of transfers is increased to say 8 or 10, sometimes the program doesn't function properly and the program will still print the output to `stdout`, but in the default format that `libcurl` will do if no `CURL_WRITEFUNCTION`/`CURL_WRITEDATA` has been included in the code, possibly suggesting nothing is being received by the `callback` function? Also in this scenario, an incorrect number of responses will be printed.

In the main `do...while` loop within `main()`, I set `chunk.memory` and `chunk.size` equal to 0 after they had been printed out. Without doing this, every time a new response was received these would continue growing. I'm unsure if this was the correct approach, however.

**Current attempt:**

Using the `libcurl` example [that can be found here](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html), I have attempted to mimic the functionality of writing the output to a callback function as seen below (instead of writing each response payload to a file).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* somewhat unix-specific */
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* curl stuff */
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/mprintf.h>

#ifndef CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX
#define CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX 0
#endif

struct CURLMsg *msg;

struct transfer {
    CURL *easy;
    unsigned int num;
    FILE *out;
};

struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};

struct MemoryStruct chunk;

#define NUM_HANDLES 1000

static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

    char *ptr = (char*)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if(!ptr) {
        /* out of memory! */
        std::cout << "not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    mem->memory = ptr;
    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}

static void setup(struct transfer *t, int num)
{
    CURL *hnd;

    hnd = t->easy = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

    /* set the same URL */
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://someurl.xyz");

    /* HTTP/2 please */
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);

    /* we use a self-signed test server, skip verification during debugging */
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

    #if (CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX > 0)
    /* wait for pipe connection to confirm */
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_PIPEWAIT, 1L);
    #endif
}

int main() {
    struct transfer trans[NUM_HANDLES];
    CURLM *multi_handle;
    int i;
    int still_running = 0; /* keep number of running handles */
    int num_transfers = 3;

    chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);
    chunk.size = 0;

    /* init a multi stack */
    multi_handle = curl_multi_init();

    for(i = 0; i < num_transfers; i++) {
        setup(&trans[i], i);

        /* add the individual transfer */
        curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, trans[i].easy);
    }

    curl_multi_setopt(multi_handle, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX);

    // Main loop
    do {
        CURLMcode mc = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);

        if(still_running) {
            /* wait for activity, timeout or "nothing" */
            mc = curl_multi_poll(multi_handle, NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);
        }

        if(mc) {
            break;
        }

        // Get response
        do {
            int queued;
            msg = curl_multi_info_read(multi_handle, &queued);
            if ((msg) && (msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE) && (msg->data.result == CURLE_OK)) {

                    // Print the response payload
                    std::cout << "size: " << chunk.size << std::endl;
                    std::cout << chunk.memory << std::endl;
                    chunk.memory = 0;
                    chunk.size = 0;

            }
            
        } while (msg);

    } while (still_running);

    for(i = 0; i < num_transfers; i++) {
        curl_multi_remove_handle(multi_handle, trans[i].easy);
        curl_easy_cleanup(trans[i].easy);
    }

    free(chunk.memory);
    curl_multi_cleanup(multi_handle);
        
    return 0;
}
```

**Summary question:**

**Q1.** How can I modify the above program to correctly save a received payload response into a `struct` or a `buffer` asynchronously so that it can be available for functionality such as printing to `stdout` or searching for `strings`?

Comment: You are passing the same memory chunk to every callback. You may need one separate chunk for each easy handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should associate the `transfer` struct with a way of accessing the output:

```
struct transfer {
    CURL *easy;
    unsigned int num;
    std::string contents;
};
```

and associate the `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` with the pointer:

```
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)t);
```

Then, `WriteMemoryCallback` becomes:

```
static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    transfer *t = (transfer *)userp;
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;    
    t->contents.append((const char *)contents, realsize);
    return realsize;
}
```

Afterwards you can find the contents in the `trans[i].contents` variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I slightly modified one line in your callback function, changing
`t->contents.append(contents, realsize);` to `t->contents.append((const char*)contents, realsize);` since it appears from C++ docs that `append` won't accept an arg of type `void` although I'm not 100% sure on my work-around. This compiles without error, however, within the `do-while` loop in `main()` I can't seem to get a printed output when using ` for (int i = 0; ...) { std::cout << trans[i].contents}`. If it's okay, would you please be able to comment if I have gone about this incorrectly? Thanks again.

Comment: Your change to `append` is correct, I included it in an edit. Don't forget to `std::cout << std::flush` or `std::cout << std::endl` to make sure output shows up in your terminal instead of being stuck in an output buffer.